# Regex for splitting hashtags, but ignore

Tags: php, regex

I have a string where I want to match hashtags after a certain "context", for example `|product`.

After `|product` I want to match the hashtags that are after that.

So this is my full string `|product#houtprint#laserprint|materiaal#hout`.

And this is my regex pattern untill now `\|product(?<product>#[^\|]+)`.
I now get a match on `#houtprint#laserprint`, but I want to get a match on them seperatly so `#houtprint` and `#laserprint`.

This is also my PHP part:

`preg_match_all("~\|".$context."(?<".$context.">#[^\|]+)~", $tags_string, $matches);`

How can I ensure that I get the products as seperate groups?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a `\G` based boundary so that `preg_match_all` could match consecutive hashtags (that follow one another after the substring you specify):

```
(?:\|product|\G(?!\A))(?<product>#[^|#]+)
```

Not sure you really need the named capture group here.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FE6690/1)

**Details**:

- `(?:\|product|\G(?!\A))` - either `|product` substring (`\|product`) or the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) (these branches may be swapped for better performance)
- `(?<product>#[^|#]+)` - a "product" named capturing group that matches

  - `#` - a hash symbol
  - `[^|#]+` - one or more chars other than `|` and `#`.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/sGtUoH):

```
$re = '/(?:\|product|\G(?!\A))(?<product>#[^|#]+)/';
$str = '|product#houtprint#laserprint|materiaal#hout';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches["product"]);
// => Array ( [0] => #houtprint [1] => #laserprint )
```